# Animation on image inside UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I made my own `toolBar` with a main action button on the middle of the bar.

When I click on a different button, my main action button image changes. I'd like to make it "obvious" by making an animation (the best would be something like `UIImageView startAnimating()`) but I fail at it.

Is there anything like the startAnimating() for the image inside `UIButton` to show the translation from an image to another ?

I dont wanna use `sleep(1)` or `usleep(200)` to block my app.

Any help or advice or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: use UIView.animateWithDuration maybe helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past is flash a color on the view to give feedback to the user that what they have done was registered with the app. In your case you could flash a color or something in between the change in images. 
I did this using a delay method I wrote which you can use by switching the color of the button, then delaying for about half a second or so, then show the next image. This will make it obvious that a change has been made. Here's the method to delay:

```
 func runAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

You can put your image swap inside the block parameter. Hope this helps